# On Swift: Met error about parentheses type writing sqrt

Tags: swift

I wrote the following code:

```
var number3 = sqrt(9)
```

and the System reports error saying that

> Variable number3 inferred to have type "()", which may be unexpected."

How can this error be? 
I found another user saying that (9) refers to (int) type instead of int type. But the `sqrt` function need an parentheses. How do you guys deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There error here is incorrect (and fixed in the latest versions of Swift). The correct error is:

```
  1> import Darwin
  2> var number3 = sqrt(9)
repl.swift:2:15: error: ambiguous use of 'sqrt'
var number3 = sqrt(9)
              ^
Darwin.sqrt:1:6: note: found this candidate
func sqrt(x: Float) -> Float
     ^
Darwin.sqrt:1:6: note: found this candidate
func sqrt(_: Double) -> Double
     ^
```

The problem is that Swift doesn't know if you want to convert the literal "3" into a Float or a Double. Rather than force it to do that, just use a Double directly:

```
  2> sqrt(9.0)
$R0: Double = 3
```

Comment: var number 3 = sqrt (9.0)

Comment: What version of Xcode is this. I can't reproduce it in either 6.4 or 7.0b5. Have you made a playground to test the one line of code? https://gist.github.com/rnapier/f2d2ea07d817708a370f

Comment: why this simple code would report error "expect declaration"?

Comment: import UIKit
import Darwin

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var displayValue: Double = 0
    displayValue = 9 //report: expect declaration    
}

Comment: class ViewController: UIViewController

Comment: {var displayValue: Double = 0

Comment: Because you didn't put `displayValue` in a function. It's inside the class definition. I'm not sure how this relates to the original question. This is very basic Swift. Have you gone through the tutorials? https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html